# AngularJS multiple layout pages

Tags: angularjs, layout, master-pages

I have an angularjs app, which has app.js (main js file where app starts), index.html file which is like a master page (gets applied to all the pages in the app). This index.html is on the root directory of my project/app.

I want to add 2-3 new pages in the app with a new master/layout page (not the index.html). I want to create index2.html which will be applied to certain pages and index3.html which will applied to certain pages.

All the 3 layouts index.html, index2.html and index3.html are completely independent/different from each other.

I tried everything but the new pages always takes index.html as a default layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is Angular UI Router. Check it out here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

You'll have to configure your index.html to be the 'home' state, with nested views for the other index files.

Check the documentation for details, but basically you'll set up your index.html file:

```
...
<body ng-app="app">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

and then in your app.js:

```
angular.module('app', [ui.router])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "partials/index.html"
      })
      .state('index2View', {
        url: "/index2",
        templateUrl: "partials/index2.html"
      });
      ... add more states for your views here ...
  });
```

You might want to look into abstract states as well, but I'm not sure what your specific requirements are from the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 

I have seen this code before, but my requirement is little different. Here the view is added in the body tag which means the <head> and <body> is going to be same for all states. I want whole different layout with <head><body> to be completely different.

Comment: Ah I see. That sounds tricky (maybe impossible?) to pull off client-side. I think you'd have to use server-side redirection for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple apps for multiple views `ng-app="what ever your app here"` after that simply add view within certain